# How do I associate an Angular Material radio button with a form control if I can't use a radio group?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

The [overview for Angular Material radio buttons](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) says:

> Radio-buttons should typically be placed inside of an `<mat-radio-group>` unless the DOM structure would make that impossible (e.g., radio-buttons inside of table cells).

I have exactly this case, with this:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-button name="group1" value="value1">Some text</mat-radio-button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-button name="group1" value="value2">Some other text</mat-radio-button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-button name="group2" value="value3">Text for value 3</mat-radio-button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-button name="group2" value="value4">Yet more text</mat-radio-button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

instead of this:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="group1">
    <mat-radio-button value="value1">Some text</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="value2">Some other text</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="group2">
    <mat-radio-button value="value3">Text for value 3</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="value4">Yet more text</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

so that I can align the buttons in a grid. This works in part, but changing the radio button selection doesn't change the value of the corresponding form control. I've tried adding `formControlName="group1"` or `[formControl]="form.get('group1')` but that causes this error:

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'group1'`.
```

How do I associate each radio button with the appropriate form control if I can't use a radio group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [response](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9457#issuecomment-360249950) by [pos1tron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704342/devon-sams) to an issue in the Angular Github repository, here's a way to accomplish this. The basic answer is to put every `<mat-radio-button>` in its own `<mat-radio-group>`, but to handle the `checked` attribute manually, like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="group1">
          <mat-radio-button
            value="value1"
            [checked]="form.get('group1').value==='value1'"
          >Some text</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </td>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="group1">
          <mat-radio-button
            value="value2"
            [checked]="form.get('group1').value==='value2'"
          >Some other text</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="group2">
          <mat-radio-button
            value="value3"
            [checked]="form.get('group2').value==='value3'"
          >Text for value 3</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </td>
      <td>
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="group2">
          <mat-radio-button
            value="value4"
            [checked]="form.get('group2').value==='value4'"
          >Yet more text</mat-radio-button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `[checked]="form.get('group1').value==='value1'"` => this is what i need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

no need to add several radio groups.

simply set a custom "formControlName" for any radio group (Not radio button!) and get selected value.

```
<form [formGroup]='reportForm' (ngSubmit)="getRadioValue()">    
<div class="form-group">
      <label id="offish-type-radio-group-label">Choose Type</label>
      <mat-radio-group aria-labelledby="offish-type-radio-group-label" 
        class="offish-type-radio-group" formControlName="offishType_">
          <mat-radio-button class="offish-type-radio-button" 
            *ngFor="let offish_type of oTypes" [value]="offish_type.value">
              {{offish_type.display}}
           </mat-radio-button>
       </mat-radio-group>             
</div>
</form>


createForm() {
    this.reportForm = this.fb.group({
      selectedDep: [, Validators.required],
      offishType_: [''],
    });
  }

  getRadioValue() {
    console.log(this.reportForm.get('offishType_').value);
  }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how that solves the use case of combining radio buttons in a table.

Comment: Hi Scott. you mentioned that "changing the radio button selection doesn't change the value of the corresponding form control." but I found out that  each radio-group can handle corresponding radio buttons value. I'm sorry if I can't understand you problem but the approach I used is completely depends on using mat-radio-group and it definitely works!